# Displaying just an image instead of text

Tags: linux, kernel, images

Is it possible to compile the linux kernel so that when it is booting up, instead of the boot up text to display and image and ONLY an image (like osx)?

Comment: This sounds like something typically done by the bootloader, e.g. [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/), a popular bootloader, not the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are typically two main components:

- The bootloader (nowadays typically grub2) on Linux boot cds typically isolinux
- A program displaying some kind of graphical interface, nowadays typically [plymouth](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth)

If you are using a Distribution targeted for consumers both should automatically be configured and installed from your distribution.